# How to get the correct frequency amplitudes in the FFT of a signal

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have the following `1Hz/10Hz` signal

```
import numpy as np

total_time = 5
sampling_frequency = 200

t = np.linspace(0, total_time , total_time * sampling_frequency)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1 * t) + 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t)

plt.plot(t, signal)
```

[image]

That's the discrete FFT I get

```
fft_spectrum = np.fft.rfft(signal)
fft_spectrum_abs = np.abs(fft_spectrum)

freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(signal.size, d=1./sampling_frequency)

plt.plot(freq, fft_spectrum_abs)
plt.xlabel("frequency, Hz")
plt.ylabel("amplitude, units")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would have expected the peak at 1Hz to have an amplitude of 1, and the peak at 10 to have an amplitude of 0.5 given my original signal. I'm having a factor of 500 off however looking at the values I'm getting on the plot - from where this factor is coming and how can I recover the original amplitudes?

Comment: related, same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175101/how-to-get-the-frequencies-and-corresponding-amplitudes-from-the-fft-of-a-signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scale the output by dividing by the number of samples, in this example, 1000. Then, because the input is real and this is a one-sided FFT and there are no negative frequency bins, you multiply by 2. That will give you the 1 and 0.5 amplitude you're looking for.

Comment: I see, I need `fft_spectrum_abs = np.abs(fft_spectrum) * 2 / (total_time * sampling_frequency)`. Perfect, that's working, thank you.