# How to get the frequencies and corresponding amplitudes from the FFT of a signal?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have the following `1.2Hz/9Hz/15Hz` signal

```
import numpy as np

total_time = 5
sampling_frequency = 100

t = np.linspace(0, total_time, total_time * sampling_frequency, endpoint=False)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1.2 * t) + 0.5*np.cos(2 * np.pi * 9 * t) + 0.75*np.sin(2 * np.pi * 15.0 * t)
plt.plot(t, signal)
```

[image]

and the discrete FFT

```
fft_spectrum = np.fft.rfft(signal)
fft_spectrum_abs = np.abs(fft_spectrum) * 2 / (total_time * sampling_frequency)

freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(signal.size, d=1./sampling_frequency)

plt.plot(freq, fft_spectrum_abs)
plt.xlabel("frequency, Hz")
plt.ylabel("amplitude, units")
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I get the frequencies and amplitudes of the FFT?

I'm using

```
[
    (amp, freq) for amp, freq in sorted(zip(fft_spectrum_abs, freq), 
    key=lambda pair: pair[0]) if amp > 0.1
]
# [(0.4999999999999984, 9.0), (0.749999999999999, 15.0), (1.0, 1.2000000000000002)]
```

which is correct but seems a bit of a hack, is there any better way to approach the problem?

Comment: related, same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173759/how-to-get-the-correct-frequency-amplitudes-in-the-fft-of-a-signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scipy's [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html). You want peaks with a height of at least 0.1, so you can specify that using the `heights` `kwarg`. When `heights` is specified, the `properties` `dict` that is returned will have a `"peak_heights"` key containing a numpy array of the peak heights (as the name suggests).

```py
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

peaks, properties = find_peaks(fft_spectrum_abs, height=0.1)
peak_freq = freq[peaks]
peak_amp = properties["peak_heights"]
print(peak_freq)  # [ 1.2  9.  15. ]
print(peak_amp)   # [1.   0.5  0.75]
```

This solution might be more robust if you have messier/noisier data.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.where` to find indices and filter both freqs and magnitudes:

```
peaks_indices = np.where(fft_spectrum_abs > 0.1)[0]
freq_and_magnitudes = list(zip(freq[peaks_indices],
                               fft_spectrum_abs[peaks_indices]))
```

Comment: That's a better way of doing it, thank you.